# Port forwarding to second router's FTP server (linked via WDS)

Tags: networking, router, ftp, port-forwarding, wds

### Problem

I am having trouble accessing my FTP server over the internet.

### Set up

This FTP server is a wds-bridged router - Netgear DG834GUv5 - 10.1.1.2 with no DHCP.

Primary Modem/Router is TP-Link Archer D7 - 10.1.1.1 with DHCP

I can access the Netgear router locally (FTP and http) and internet is accessible throughout the network.

### Results

No matter what port number I forward to my Netgear router, it won't let me access my FTp server from the web. I have other HTTP servers on my network, eg DVR, which are accessible and thus port forwarded with no problems.

#### Lan scans results

Working well - FTP is successful.
[image: Lan scan results - local]

#### Port scans results from http://mxtoolbox.com/PortScan.aspx

Port 21 has error and could not connect to my FTP server.
[image: Port scans results over the web]

### Possible Ideas

I think the primary modem/router has correct port forwarding rules and maybe the issue lies with the Netgear router. I have checked and the Netgear should be accepting internet FTP connections but is not in reality.

Any ideas to help me FTP over internet?

#### Notes

ISP is not blocking the FTP port 21 as the primary modem/router had FTP working. I need two FTP servers due to a physical location requirement hence I can't use the primary modem/router FTP server.

Comment: Your TP-Link Archer D7 also has FTP server functionality. Did you get it out of the way by making sure it was disabled, and that its control port was set to something other than 21? I would do both just in case the firmware is buggy and reserves the control port even when the FTP server is disabled.

Comment: Hmm, never mind I guess, that doesn't explain why other ports can't be forwarded to port 21 on your Netgear.

Comment: Do you have any firewall rules set on the Netgear?

Comment: My netgear firewall is fully disabled. I suspect it has todo with the WDS bridge. Although local networking seems fine from the web browser, the TP-Link Archer D7 shows some interesting data:
IP 10.1.1.2 
MAC 00:00:00:00:00:00 (mac not right - but linked correctly in wizard)
packets 565
Bytes 43,961

Comment: @Spiff I turned off my TP-Link D7 FTP server. I believe Port Forward is fine, probably the WDS is the problem. I'll update soon,

Comment: SIGH... `arp -a` on windows CMD gives the correct mac address. I still can't access this FTP server from outside. Error: "Connection timed out
"